# Enabling permalinks on a VPS-hosted Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have a VPS with LAMP installed, on which I run several websites, each of them redirected via CNAME to a subfolder /domain.com/htdocs.

One of these websites is a wordpress. I'm trying to activate permalinks for my pages. Following the directions of [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps) I've tried to modify the config of the apache2/sites-available/domain.com file to change the AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All.

I'm still getting the same 404 error :

> The requested URL /page-name/ was not found on this server.

I've checked on my FTP, my .htaccess file exists and has the correct permalink redirect:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The only way I've managed to activate permalinks is by putting index.php/ before it:

mywebsite.com/index.php/page-name/

Any idea on how to fix this? Would be immensely grateful, I've been trying to make this work for hours now!

Thanks in advance,

Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. I just needed to load the mod_rewrite module with the command a2enmod rewrite.

Hope that'll help someone!